# Jackson: Map Deserialization

Tags: java, json, jackson

I want to deserialize the following json-string to this map `Map<String, IAnimal>`. My problem is that the values of the animals in the json-string does not contain any type information and are only dependant of the keys.

```
{
    "dog": {
        "age": 5
    },
    "cat": {
        "age": 2
    }
}

interface IAnimal {

}

class Dog implements IAnimal {
    int age;
    // getter & setter
}

class Cat implements IAnimal {
    int age;
    // getter & setter
}
```

Comment: Why is this question downvoted? It is a legitimate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to write a custom deserializer for this:

```
public class AnimalDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<IAnimal> {

    private Map<String, Class<? extends IAnimal>> registry =  new HashMap<String, Class<? extends Animal>>();  

    public AnimalDeserializer()  {  
        super(IAnimal.class);  
    }  

    public void registerAnimal(String uniqueAttribute, Class<? extends IAnimal> animalClass) {  
        registry.put(uniqueAttribute, animalClass);  
    }  

    @Override  
    public IAnimal deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {  
        ObjectMapper mapper = (ObjectMapper) parser.getCodec();  
        ObjectNode root = (ObjectNode) mapper.readTree(parser);  

        Class<? extends IAnimal> animalClass = null;  
        Iterator<Entry<String, JsonNode>> iterator = root.getFields();  
        boolean found = false;
        while (!found &&iterator.hasNext()) {  
            Entry<String, JsonNode> element = elementsIterator.next();  
            String name = element.getKey();  

            if(registry.containsKey(name)) {  
                animalClass = registry.get(name);  
                found = true;
            }
        }  

        if(animalClass == null) {
            return null;  
        } else {
            return mapper.readValue(root, animalClass);  
        }
    }  
}
```

When you instantiate your deserializer, you will have to register the property names that map to the appropriate class:

```
AnimalDeserializer deserializer = new AnimalDeserializer();  
deserializer.registerAnimal("dog", Dog.class);  
deserializer.registerAnimal("cat", Cat.class);
```

You can also do this in the constructor for `AnimalDeserializer` if you know what the properties are going to be before-hand.

I got this from **example 6** from [this](http://programmerbruce.blogspot.com/2011/05/deserialize-json-with-jackson-into.html) very-useful post.

Comment: This works. Thank you. But I am wondering why there is no simple solution with annotations.

Comment: @Maxii Unfortunately not. It would be nice to have an annotation that works based on the presence or absence of a property, but there isn't one unfortunately.